# @import with Sass not combining files

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to sass and I'm trying to import a parent theme's css in a Magento application.

I have it working to an extent but not with the result I was expecting.

In my **styles.scss** folder I have:

```
@import "../../../rwd/default/css/styles.css";
```

I have run the `sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css` in the terminal and the resulting **styles.css** file has:

```
@import url(../../../rwd/default/css/styles.css);
```

In the [sass guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide) it says:

> CSS has an import option that lets you split your CSS into smaller,
>   more maintainable portions. The only drawback is that each time you
>   use @import in CSS it creates another HTTP request. Sass builds on top
>   of the current CSS @import but instead of requiring an HTTP request,
>   Sass will take the file that you want to import and combine it with
>   the file you're importing into so you can serve a single CSS file to
>   the web browser.

So I was expecting SASS to import the css as plain old css rules rather than using the @import rule, so my styles.css would look something like:

```
/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * Corrects `block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Corrects `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 */
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*
 * Prevents modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling for `hidden` attribute not present in IE 8/9.
 */
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Base
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * 1. Sets default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
 * Removes default margin.
 */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * Addresses `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

/*
 * Improves readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Typography
   ========================================================================== */
/*
 * Addresses `h1` font sizes within `section` and `article` in Firefox 4+,
 * Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in IE 8/9, Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/*
 * Addresses style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 */
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

/*
 * Corrects font family set oddly in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 */
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/*
 * Improves readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
 */
pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
 * Sets consistent quote types.
 */
q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

/*
 * Addresses inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
 * Prevents `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

That way I would have a styles.css on production which didn't use the @import rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it to work by following this article:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

@import by default looks for a Sass file to import directly, but if the is a .css file or if the filename is a url it will compile to a CSS @import rule. Both of which were the case for me.

So my solution was to copy the css file I wanted to import & rename it rwd_styles.scss & changed my scss import rule to `@import "rwd_styles.scss";` and it worked as I had hoped.

Comment: You can leave it as `@import "rwd_styles"`

Comment: To clarify Adam's comment, you don't need to rename the .css file to .scss if you simply leave the extension off of the .css file when importing it.

Comment: This is odd. But I had a css file that I tried to import (.css extension), and according to the docs, it said you can import it fine to compile them together, just leave out the `.css` filename, but when I did, it said it couldn't find it. I renamed it to `.scss`, nothing else, and it worked.